# Acceder a propiedad de un modelo Sequelize nodejs TypeScript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, express, sequelize.js

Estoy insertando un usuario en la base de datos pero no me deja acceder a la propiedad password de mi modelo, estoy usando Typescript.

Tengo el modelo importado en mi .ts de la siguiente manera

```
import Usuario from '../models/usuario';
    
// Aquí creo el usuario
const newusuario = Usuario.build(req.body);
// Aqui quiero acceder a la propiedad name
console.log(newusuario.name); 
// Aquí insertaria el usuario en la base de datos (No da error)
await newusuario.save();
```

El newusuario.name me lanza el siguiente error

> La propiedad 'name' no existe en el tipo 'Model<any, any>'.ts(2339)

El modelo lo tengo creado así:

```
import { DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import db from '../db/connection';

const Usuario = db.define('usuarios', {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    avatar: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    state: {
        type: DataTypes.TINYINT
    },
});

export default Usuario;
```

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: has podido encontrar la solución. Estoy en el mismo dilema, no puedo acceder a las propiedades, una vez creada.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo unico que hice fue declarar la como any en el tipo de la constatante asi:
const newusuario: any = Usuario.build(req.body);

Answer (score 0):

Estaba con el mismo problema, lo que pasa es que al modelo de sequelize le falta incorporar una "interfaz" (de ahí el mensaje Model any any), según la documentación es de la forma:
primero: importar "Model" de sequelize
segundo: incorporarlo al Modelo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Listo!
[link documentación](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/)

Comment: Si podes poner el código como texto y no como imagen sería lo ideal